# tkinter - TypeError : __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I'm making a quiz and I keep getting an error in my code whenever I run it. I'm using tkinter, which is pretty new to me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

````
def name_collection(self):
      name = self.entry_box.get()
      if str.isalpha(name) == True and len(name) >0 and len(name) <=10:
        name_list.append(name)
        Start(root)
      elif str.isalpha(name) == False:
        messagebox.showerror("Please enter your name again:","Check you are only using alphabetical letters. Special characters and numbers cannot be accepted.")
      elif len(name) <0:
        messagebox.showerror("Please enter your name again:","Please check you have entered your name before you continue")
      elif len(name) >10:
        messagebox.showerror("Please enter your name again:","Make sure you've entered a name up to 10 characters")
        name_list.append(name)
      self.quiz_frame.grid_forget()
      self.quiz_frame.forget()
      Close(root)

class Close:
  def __init__ (self):
    background = "Oldlace"
    self.close_box.title("Close box")
    self.close_frame = Frame (self.close_box, width=1000, height = 1000, bg = background)
    self.close_frame.grid()

    close_heading = Label (self.close_frame, text = 'Well Done', font = ('Tw Cen Mt',22, 'bold'), bg = background, pady = 15)
    close_heading.grid(row = 4, pady = 20)```
````

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but `Close(root)` should be `Close()` or `def __init__ (self, master)` is needed.

Comment: `Close(root)` is the same as `root = Close()` right? So if `master` is needed, it should be root = Close(Tk) or something

Comment: This is not about tkinter, but about classes in Python in general. `self` is actually a required parameter. But you don't need to explicitly pass it when you do `Close()`. This `1 positional argument` in the error message refers to `self`. `def __init__(self)` means that the method (function) of the class does not take any additional arguments. When you execute `Close(root)`, you are passing a second argument to `__init__`, which is not initially listed there.

Comment: _"Close(root) is the same as root = Close() right?"_ - no, it is not the same.